Найти все значения из буфера обмена на вебстранице
Пытаюсь скопировать числа из Excel строк и вставить их в хром, чтобы найти и выделить эти значения на вебстранице (они ограничены друг от друга табуляцией). Как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо за помощь и внимание.


Покажите желаемый результат. Сейчас не понятно, куда вы и что вставляете. и причем тут табуляция с буфером?

При вставке из Excel в консоль браузера эти значения ограничены табуляцией.
Ну, чтобы эти значения на вебстранице можно было найти (например подсвечены как при quick search (CTRL+F))

Вы это хотите сделать для какого то конкретного сайта или для всех? Если для конкретного - есть ли у вас доступ к нему? Может добавлять скрипты? Если ко всем, то умеете ли вы создавать расширения для браузера?

Изначально для конкретного (да, можно добавлять js скрипты), но и создать расширение не проблема

Вот тут есть пример. Вам надо разбить ваш документ на составные части, Так же рекурсивно пробежаться по все дочерним нодам. Искать ноды с именем "#text", сверять значения с переданным списком и если совпало, то заменять на элемент, что бы он выделился. Ну а сам список превратить в массив, разбив как раз по символу табуляции
